# fixing HDF5 dependency error on installation

Tags: julia, hdf5

I am trying to use the `HDF5` package in Julia 1.9.3 on Windows.

In a clean environment, I have added the package as:
`] add HDF5`

it prints out:

``` 0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 0 seconds. 21 already precompiled.                                           1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run ``import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()`` or load the package ```

I ran the command `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` and it gives me no error.

calling `using HDF5` in the REPL also gives no error.

However, each time I  reload the script and do:
`Pkg.instantiate()` I get the same error as in the beginning: `1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run` import Pkg; Pkg.precompile() `or load the package`

How can I see which dependency is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `using HDF5` in the repl, it should give a more detailed error.

Comment: Hi, gives me no error. Only when I try to `add` or `instantiate`. I also cannot see which dependency is giving an error

Comment: What does the output of `] status` look like?

Comment: just this: `[f67ccb44] HDF5 v0.17.1`